# What to learn to be a UI Developer (HTML, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery)?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, css, dom, user-interface

I'm learning to be a UI Developer (HTML, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery)

I need advanced tutorials with examples for UI Developer by using jQuery. Please share your link and tutorials.

Comment: lesson 1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I first started learning jQuery this helped me a whole bunch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810

Good luck on your journey, I wish you the best and hope you get to where you want to be!